# Unable to serialize/deserialize parameters passed to WCF method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, dynamics-crm-2011

I've got this interface, from a WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
public interface IQuerySageService
{

    [OperationContract]
    CustomerLedger GetBillingContact(string crmAccountNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    ImportCrmInvoicesResponse ImportCrmInvoices(List<New.Xrm.Entities.Invoice> invoices);


}
```

And the method refered above is from this class:

```
internal static class KnownTypesProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

        types.Add(typeof(New.Xrm.Entities.InvoiceDetail));

        return types;
    }
}
```

But when invoking `ImportCrmInvoices` (`Invoice` has `InvoiceDetail` children) from the client (a CRM workflow), I get the following error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:invoices. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'New.Xrm.Entities.InvoiceDetail' with data contract name
>   'InvoiceDetail:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/New.Xrm.Entities'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details."

I thought this `ServiceKnownType` decoration would do the trick from what I've read, but apparently not.

The types (Invoice, InvoiceDetail) are contained within an assembly, refered by both the client and the server (namespace `New.Xrm.Entities`)

Now, the physical CS file that holds those types is huge (7MB), and barely editable. So maybe I'm missing a `DataContract` decoration somewhere, but I don't want to go in this file to add it.

Any other ways to achieve this ?

Comment: Serializing/Deserializing early bound entities is a pain and also will increase dependency and not to mention the 1001 unnecessary members that it holds. Try to flatten it out by using a poco with just the members you need, it is much cleaner and leaner this way.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I think that's what it'll come to... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up have having the WCF service doing it's own look ups in CRM. The ImportCrmInvoices method accepts a list of GUIDS and fetches the data about them itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is to use the KnownTypes attribute on your parent  DataContract class from which your child classes derive.

> The KnownTypeAttribute class allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx)

The KnownTypes attribute can either take a type parameter, or you can provide the name of a method in that class that returns an array of valid types.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownTypes(typeof(InvoiceDetail)]
public class Invoice
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeProperty {get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class InvoiceDetail : Invoice
{
}
```

Comment: I added details in my question, regarding where these types are held and I don't want to edit the file. It's huge and inconvient to edit and generated by a tool.

Comment: Does the tool generate a partial class?  If so, you could just create a partial that applies the known types attribute.